# How to boot or "enter" into Ubuntu 11.04 on PS3 after installing it?

Tags: 11.04, ps3

After failing to install the Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop version (burned on a DVD, because ISO's file size was 726 MB), I tried the alternate version (about 686 MB) which I burned on CD.

During the installation process, I manually partitioned the hard drive using ext3. After the installation, the CD ejects itself and I hit "continue". In the k boot prompt I hit "enter" on my the keyboard. I see a welcome message in a dark background (a kind of full screen terminal/console called CLI I think) and was asked to enter my user name and password.

After that, instead of booting into the beautiful desktop of Ubuntu, I saw this:

```
ubuntu@my_name$
```

It was like a line of command I think, where you can use "sudo" commands. It is called a non-graphic mode I think.

My *real* problem is to enter Ubuntu 11.04 with the chocolate-colored  background and the African music drum. I tried many commands to boot into the graphic mode of the system such as Ctr+Alt+F7 but nothing happened. In this case, I just saw numbers showing available blocks. **I don't understand.**

I also tried `startx` and `sudo startx` without result.
I **do** bought a PS3 **both** for gaming and for Ubuntu because I can't afford buying a PC.

Comment: You're welcome. Please use the prepared methods to emphasize text, as there are: bold, italics, `<S>` code instead of CAPITALS and "citation", and make some paragraphs to invite readers. There are buttons above the textfield and a preview below, where you immediately get feedback.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you get when you run `startx`? Maybe you don't have the desktop user interface installed. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thank you for tour answer, I'll try it this night. If i remember well, typing startx gave me a message talking about JOB impossible.

Comment: in order to try "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" should i have the CD inserted?

Comment: And must my ps3 be connected to the Internet to have the "apt-get install Ubuntu desktop" command functional?

Comment: It should work if you have the CD inserted, but I'd suggest having it connected to the internet so you can run all the updates with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: It worked well! Thanks for your help! Open office org is working too.. But i don't see Blender. Is it really present on the  ubuntu ps3

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Please mark the answer as the solution by clicking on the checkmark next to it. This will help people searching for answers. Blender is not installed by default. You can either install it using the Ubuntu Software Center, or with the following command, `sudo apt-get install blender`